# Cannot export compiler generated assignment operator / copy constructor when using .DEF files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and have run across a problem when trying to export compiler generated assignment operators (and copy constructors).

Here is the code:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) Example {

  public:

     Example () {}
};
```

When I create a dll from this code, I get the following exported symbols:

```
      1    0 00001010 ??0Example@@QAE@XZ = ??0Example@@QAE@XZ (public: __thiscall Example::Example(void))
      2    1 00001000 ??4Example@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z = ??4Example@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z (public: class Example & __thiscall Example::operator=(class Example const &))
```

Ordinal 2 is a compiler generated assignment operator.

I assumed (incorrectly so it seems) that I can use a .DEF file to export these same two symbols and remove the dllexport directive. I want to do this in a much larger project to hide symbols.

```
class Example {

  public:

     Example () {}
};
```

and the .DEF file:

```
LIBRARY "dll"
EXPORTS
??0Example@@QAE@XZ
??4Example@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z
```

When I try to build this, I get the following link error:

```
dll.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class Example & __thiscall Example::operator=(class Example const &)" (??4Example@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z)
```

It seems that when dllexport is removed, the compiler no longer generates the assignment operator. Why would this be?

Comment: You have to give the compiler a good reason to generate the code for these functions if it otherwise can tell that they are not used anywhere.  Using __declspec is such a good reason, a linker directive is not.  The relevant MSDN article [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xa0d9ste.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Hans for answering. The thing is though, that the compiler doesn't seem to be generating these functions. I can see that by examination of the .obj file. It's not really a linker issue. What the linker reports is correct because the compiler hasn't generated the functions and I don't think that the compiler could possibly know whether these functions would be used or not.

Comment: It does know.  You are not taking the next step, putting the class in a .h file and #including it in the source file of another project.  At which point the compiler is happy to generate the code for inline methods, if needed.

Comment: Hi Hans. What I saw was a little different, but I could be misunderstanding this. So this is what I see, giving a basic example. libDLLA defines classA in a .h file and without dllexport. I cannot include the decorated name for the generated functions as they give me a linker error. libDLLB includes and imports classA by including its .h file and what I get then is an undefined on the missing generated functions. So in libDLLB I am still not getting the inline functions generated.

Comment: Doh!!! I think I found the issue. I'm using __declspec(dllimport) in the other libraries. Looks like I don't need that.

Comment: Thanks Hans for pointing me in the right direction. Always good to get a second pair of eyes on a problem.